# Using "I don't think" to express an opinion

Tags: negation, double-negation

This morning, I used the phrase

> I didn't sleep very well, I don't think.

when speaking to my Colombian friend and he asked me what on earth I was talking about.

I thought about it and realised that this is idiomatic usage and that despite saying "I don't think" you are actually expressing what you *do* think.

Generally the form is `[expression of negative opinion using negative grammar] + "I don't think"`.

For example:

> I didn't sleep very well, I don't think. => I think I slept poorly.
>
> I won't get there very early, I don't think. => I think I will arrive late.

The first part is an opinion about what something is *not*, rather than what it *is*, i.e. *my sleep was **not** good*; *my arrival will **not** be early*. You wouldn't say:

> I slept badly, I don't think.

It seems like "I don't think" is a way of intensifying the sentence, because it doesn't modify the meaning of the initial statement in any way. We seem to use it to express disappointment with a situation, but there might be more reasons.

1. Is there a name for this usage?
2. Do you use it to express anything other than disappointment?

Comment: As for your second question, I don't think it's confined to "disappointment." Consider: _I won't be volunteering for that detail, I don't think_ (in other words, "Let some other sucker get roped into that"). Or: _I won't be quitting my job anytime soon, I don't think_ (uttered by someone who likes their job).

Comment: @J.R. It is idiomatically correct, but in my experience nowadays unfashionable, perhaps because it can sound like a sloppy double negative. I tend to avoid it, unless the meaning is obvious, as it is in your second example, above.  I would tend to say *I don't think I slept very well last night*.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer is, they're two different sentences - but the second one is kind of truncated: "I don't think (so)". So, the second part is not *attached* to the first part, but reiterating the negative and confirming it.

Comment: I think there's some truth to that. In the example of _I didn't sleep very well, I don't think_, that second part might be expressing a bit of uncertainty, not disappointment. It's a shortened form of _I didn't sleep very well; at least, I don't think I did._

Comment: I actually quite like this theory; I think William Bloom's link in his answer may confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

It's called **negation**, albeit a special form of it used more in informal communication.

It doesn't express disappointment (although your tone when you say it might).

This statement...

> I think Hillary Clinton will not run for president.

...is the equivalent of this statement...

> I don't think Hillary Clinton will run for president.

...and a less formal, more idiomatic way of saying that is...

> Hillary Clinton will not run for president, I don't think.

Notice this formulation combines the other two. It's technically a double-negative. It's fine face-to-face, but don't use it in formal communication.

Read more about negation at the following website. There's a section on negating "think" at the bottom.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/negation

> ### Not … I don’t think
>
> There are some cases where we can use reporting verbs such as imagine,
>   suppose and think in end position, after the reported clause. In such
>   cases, both clauses may have a negative verb:
>
> *He’s not a teacher, I don’t think.* (or *I don’t think he’s a teacher.*)
>
> Not: *I don’t think he’s not a teacher.*
>
> *I won’t be very late tonight, I shouldn’t imagine.* (or *I shouldn’t
>   imagine I’ll be very late tonight.*)
>
> Not: *I shouldn’t imagine I won’t be late.*
>
> Sometimes we use not in front position where a following reduced
>   clause (a clause with something omitted but which is understood) also
>   has a negative form:
>
> A: *Have you seen Leila?*
>
> B: *Not today, I haven’t.* (I haven’t seen Leila/her.)
>
> A: *Is Tony working at the university?*
>
> B: *Not now, he isn’t. He used to.*

Answer (score 0):

The historical use of "I don't think" is to negate a previous disingenuous positive comment (often deliberately exaggerated) to highlight a deliberate irony.

It's exactly equivalent to: "You're a genius - not!"

The "pseudo double-negative" use is a common modern misuse of language by people who don't think about what they say.

[www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/i-dont-think](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/i-dont-think)